# How to calculate distance of a object of known size using all the camera properties?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, distance, camera-calibration

So I have used opencv to calibrate and calculate the intrinsic and extrinsic matrix of the camera. So using these and also the object length or size, can I calculate the distance of the object from the camera?

I currently have the world points for one set of pixel value.

```
# Given point in image coordinates (in pixels)
image_point = np.array([1232, 552, 1])  # Replace with your actual x, y pixel coordinates

# Given intrinsic matrix K
K = np.array([
   [[2947.2353515625, 0.0, 2059.852294921875], [0.0, 2947.2353515625, 1039.6634521484375], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
])  # Replace fx, fy, cx, cy with your actual intrinsic parameters
# or you can get it using device.readCalibration().getCameraIntrinsics()

# Invert the intrinsic matrix
K_inv = np.linalg.inv(K)

# Convert to normalized camera coordinates
normalized_camera_point = K_inv @ image_point

# Given CAM_to_WORLD transformation matrix
CAM_to_WORLD = np.array([[ 0.99475127,  0.01237097,  0.10157198,  0.08476004],
 [ 0.01436607,  0.96594656, -0.25834254,  0.14530805],
 [-0.10130906,  0.25844576,  0.96069884, -0.28102537],
 [ 0.,          0. ,         0. ,         1.,        ]])  # Replace with your actual transformation matrix

# Transform to world coordinates
homogeneous_world_point = CAM_to_WORLD @ np.append(normalized_camera_point, 1)

# Convert to Cartesian coordinates
world_point = homogeneous_world_point[:3] / homogeneous_world_point[3]

print("World Point:", world_point)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but this could be on blog `PyImageSearch`. You can also ask on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: [Find distance from camera to object using Python and OpenCV - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/)

Comment: [Measuring distance between objects in an image with OpenCV - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/)